# Wordpress show blank page on useradd - Nginx,HHVM,MariaDB

Tags: wordpress, nginx, hhvm

right now I got the following problem:
Always when I try to add an user or reset a password I only get redirected to a blank page.
First of all I thought it is a problem with sendmail or nginx-redirect (it's my first setup with nginx). But both methods are working from within a test.php-file written by myself.

Also the wordpress debug flag doesn't help anything, because there is no output on the blank page. I tried in different browser, but always the same outcome.

My setup is pretty similar to this [Tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/wordpress-installation-with-nginx-mariadb-and-hhvm-on-ubuntu/). I added the sendmail package. My nginx sites-available/default looks like this:

```
server {
  server_name www.***.de;
  rewrite ^ http://***.de$request_uri? permanent;
}
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;
        include hhvm.conf;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
#            error_page 418 = @rewrite;
#            recursive_error_pages on;
             try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^[^=](.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;

            if ( $uri = /index.php ) {
                    break;
            }

#            if ( !-e $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
#                    return 418;
#            }

            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

**- l1am0**

Comment: have you checked server logs for errors. sounds like a fatal error and would likely be in apache error logs.

Comment: Sadly the nginx error logs don't help me at all. They are not covering any problems regarding this files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found the bug, but managed to install the setup: WordPress, Nginx, HHVM, Letsencrypt

It was done by the following steps:

- apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
- apt-get install sendmail mailutils
- And the rest setup was done by: https://easyengine.io/

BR